# Splitting large svn repository into multiple git repositories and tracking history across "svn mv"

Tags: migration, git-svn

I've got a large svn repository which I'm splitting and migrating to several git repositories.

So this single svn repository,

```
software/project_1/
        /project_2/
        /project_X/
```

will become these git repositories:

```
repositories/project_1.git
            /project_2.git
            /project_X.git
```

I'm having trouble preserving the history for files that cross multiple git repositories due to an `svn mv` sometime in their history.

For example, consider the following repository:

```
software/project_1/<core_stuff>
                  /project_X/
```

Development happened under `software/project_1/project_X/` for a while before it was `svn mv`'ed into a standalone `software/project_X/`

Now, for all of my `project_X` history, `project_1.git` has the pre-`svn mv` stuff, and `project_X.git` has the post-`svn mv` stuff.

Is this situation common? Is it possible to meaningfully track the history of files in such a situation?